# AMPscript, how to learn?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm a designer and I need to learn AMPscript.

I wonder if you know any courses.

And also do you need to be a developer or know programming languages ​​to learn AMPscript?

Comment: This forum is not typically designed for questions like this. Its more about actual problems you want to face and where you got stuck. You should always have shown what you tried so far and what you want to achieve.

This way you kind of learn the most ;) Trial and Error and ask for help in communities like these, if you have no mentor

Answer (score 9):

Just try it and take some of these:

### Documentation

- [AMPscript Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/syntaxGuide.htm) (official documentation)
- [The AMPscript Guide](https://ampscript.guide/) by Eliot Harper and Adam Spriggs
- [Salesforce Stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript), AMPscript tag
  ​

### Websites

- [Gregory Gifford](https://gortonington.com/)
- [Mark Cassady](http://salesforcemc.com/)
- [Zuzanna Jarczyńska](https://www.sfmarketing.cloud)
- [HowToSFMC](https://www.howtosfmc.com)
- [Adam Spriggs](https://sprignaturemoves.com/)
- [Ivan Razine](https://ampscript.xyz/)
- [Jackson Chen](https://ampscript.com/)
- [Lukas Lunow](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/)

​

### Twitter

- [Corinna Cohen](https://twitter.com/@cwessel25)
- [Chester Bullock](https://twitter.com/@coskier)
- [Guilda Hilaire](https://twitter.com/@guilda_h)
- [Zuzanna Jarczynska](https://twitter.com/@ZJarczynska)
- [Adam Spriggs](https://twitter.com/@wvpv)
- [Gregory Gifford](https://twitter.com/@GregoryRGifford)
- [Tony Zupancic](https://twitter.com/@TonyZupancic)
- [Ivan Razine](https://twitter.com/@RazineIva)
- [Aysha Marie Zouain](https://twitter.com/@blackendhonesty)
- [Genna Matson](https://twitter.com/@gemliza)
- [Jason](https://twitter.com/@HelloJasoco)
  ​

### YouTube

- [Marketing Cloud](https://www.youtube.com/user/MarketingCloudVideo) (official)
- [mcChat - Eliot Harper](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyxpMhYIPxuRcyHNOJw_bVA)
- [Melbourne SFMC Developer Group](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrXVpLuS4d45a5BZpNXtrwQ)
  ​

### Trailhead

- [Explore AMPscript](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-programmatic-languages/explore-ampscript) Unit
- [Salesforce Marketing Cloud Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/)

Comment: Feel free to edit these ;)